# How to let EC2 instance know when new image pushed to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to let EC2 instance know that a new Docker image was pushed to the repository in ECR? Do I also send some message to the some kind of queue? Or there is some ECR service that can send some events to my EC2 instance that a new image was just pushed?

I basically want to pull and run the new version of the image whenever it is pushed to the ECR ( some sort of CD) is that possible with some of the AWS services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

1. Install the SSM agent on the EC2 machine (and give the EC2 instance a role that has the `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy)
2. Use EventBridge to create a rule that gets triggered when the push to the ECR repository happens. EventBridge will create a role with the required permissions for it to use
3. Configure the EventBridge rule to trigger SSM's Run Command with the `AWS-RunShellScript` document and with your command (`docker pull...`) as a parameter

Useful links:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-cwe-target.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-eventbridge.html#ecr-eventbridge-bus

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the idea Paolo. I will try that out and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @huudyy cool, let me know. If the answer worked for you don't forget to upvote it and accept it

Comment: so now I am trying to find the logs from that command that was executed on the EC2 after push to ECR. Setting up the EventBridge with that rule set up as well seems to work as I see it's been triggered on the monitoring tab, however I do not see the new image to be pulled on the EC2 and cannot find any logs, also looking back at your answer do I need two separate rules?

Comment: @huudyy are you using SSM to send the command like I mentioned?

Comment: yes, but I am not quite sure how the rule knows which EC2 instance should it run on. The rule is triggered and fails as I see it in the CloudWatch but cannot find any info what exactly failed. Maybe you got some Discord so I can show you some screenshots?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246147/discussion-between-paolo-and-huudyy).

Comment: Appreciate your detailed discussion in the chat; it really helped me sort out the permissions issue that I was having getting my script to execute.